# Rating bar not showing all stars

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have the following code for `RatingBar`.

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:rating="4"
    android:id="@+id/product_rating"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.0"
    android:max="5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>
```

But even though I have used the following attributes to set the Max Stars and step size and max values, **I should have got five visible stars. But....** I get the result like this:

[image]

If I take a look at nexus 10 landscape  I get this :
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Addition : I am using this layout again the same problem

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30">
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_bar_product_stats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:max="5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating_string_product_stats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and not `android:layout_width="0dp"`
Because if use `android:layout_width="0dp"` and set `android:layout_weight="1"` it may show more than 5 stars based on the device width.

**Update 1**
As per your code above if I use this I get all 5 stars only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="30">
<RatingBar
  android:id="@+id/rating_bar_product_stats"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:max="5"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
  android:text="4.4"
  android:id="@+id/rating_string_product_stats"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

See the output below

[image]

Comment: why cant i get 5 stars and get just 2 or half or so

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the parent layout it's quite difficult to say. It looks link you have a `LinearLayout` where you have not set `orientation="vertical"` (unless you want a horizontal layout). Also your setting of the `android:layout_width="0dp"` is odd without a layout_weight attribute.

I would suggest:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1"
    android:isIndicator="true" />
```

and in your code:

```
findViewById(R.id.rating).setRating(int)
```

If you give me more of the layout (the parent container) I could probably help more.

Comment: there is only one parent and that is constraint layout

Answer (score 1):

Rating bar takes UI width according to size of a single star so if the space alloted to rating bar is less then lesser stars are shown and if space alloted to rating bar is more than required then stars shown are more.
So there are 2 options to resolve it either you can fix the width of rating bar according to 5 stars or take 5 check boxes or image view which ever you are comfortable with and set your logic for them.